Azure function in golang, how to get subscription id?
I've got an Azure function written in Go, and I need to get the Subscription ID where the function is running.
How can I get the Subscription ID from inside my go-coded Azure function?
I've looked at env vars and the http.Request contents, and neither of those contains the Subscription ID.

Refer to link to Create a Go  function in Azure using Visual Studio Code

We can use the SubscriptionsClient from the armresources package. Below is the code to retrieve the Subscription ID programmatically using the Azure SDK for Go.
To install the required packages, use the following commands:
go get github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/resources/armsubscriptions

go get github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity


I followed this link for azidentity and this link for creating a function in Go using Visual Studio Code.
The following Azure Function code retrieves the Subscription ID using azidentity and armsubscriptions in Go:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azidentity"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/resources/armsubscriptions"
)


func helloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    message := "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string for a personalized response.\n"
    name := r.URL.Query().Get("name")
    if name != "" {
        message = fmt.Sprintf("Hello, %s. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.\n", name)
    }
    fmt.Fprint(w, message)
}


func printSubscriptions(ctx context.Context) {
    
    cred, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to obtain credential: %v", err)
    }


    subClient, err := armsubscriptions.NewClient(cred, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create subscriptions client: %v", err)
    }

    pager := subClient.NewListPager(nil)

    for pager.More() {
        page, err := pager.NextPage(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to retrieve subscription page: %v", err)
        }
        for _, subscription := range page.Value {
            fmt.Printf("Subscription ID: %s\n", *subscription.SubscriptionID)
            fmt.Printf("Subscription Name: %s\n", *subscription.DisplayName)
        }
    }
}

func main() {

    ctx := context.Background()

    fmt.Println("Fetching Azure Subscriptions:")
    printSubscriptions(ctx)

    listenAddr := ":8080"
    if val, ok := os.LookupEnv("FUNCTIONS_CUSTOMHANDLER_PORT"); ok {
        listenAddr = ":" + val
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/api/HttpExample", helloHandler)
    log.Printf("About to listen on %s. Go to http://127.0.0.1%s/", listenAddr, listenAddr)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(listenAddr, nil))
}



Output:

